# VBA outlook - save as email

Tags: vba, outlook, save-as

I was trying to save my current email to a folder.

I modified my code a bit. However, there is an error.

```
*438 : object doesn't support this property or method.*
```

on this code:

```
GetCurrentItem().SaveAsFile StrFile, olMSG
```

**My VBA code:**

```
Public fso As New FileSystemObject
Public objApp As Outlook.Application
Public OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Public strPath As String
Public StrFile As String

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object

    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function


Sub saveMyEmail()

      strPath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\my vba\fso\"


      StrFile = strPath & Worksheets("Main").Range("A1").Value & ".msg"
      GetCurrentItem().SaveAsFile StrFile, olMSG



Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code in the Outlook VBA environment:

```
Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector
```

You need to set the objApp object to the instance of the Application class or use the global Application property in Outlook VBA.

Comment: hi Eugene, I have modified my code a bit on the question. Could you kindly have a look please.

Comment: Hi Eugene, No worrys man. I have figured it out. thanks for your help!